# Change key value of dictionary using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have python code to parse out a CSV as follows

```
    def process_incoming_file(self, bucket, key, event):
        try:
            line_count = 0
            timestamp = 0
            
                  
            print('processing data')

            response = self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            decoded_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded_content)

            reader = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
            rows = list(reader)

            for row in rows:
                
                fid = uuid.uuid4()

                if line_count == 0:
                    keys = row
                    print('keys', keys)
                    line_count += 1
                else:
                    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:27700') #British National Grid
                    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') #WGS84
                    x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
                    x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
                    row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
                    json_doc = {}
                    

                    for idx,el in enumerate(row):
                        if keys[idx].lower() in ['time', 'date serviced']:
                            timestamp = self.format_timestring(row[idx])
                        else:
                            json_doc[keys[idx]] = row[idx]
                            
        

                    print(row[0])
                    print (fid)
                    print(timestamp)
                    print(json_doc)
                    line_count += 1


        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return
```

The above codes then return my results as:

```
108
df44d8ef-1ace-40cb-9cb6-ebbce0bb78ed
1579219200
{'Object': '108', 'Easting': 50.15466792673487, 'Northing': -5.066927538249519}
```

However, I would like to update the key names from 'Easting' to 'Latitude', and 'Northing' to 'Longitude', like this:

```
108
df44d8ef-1ace-40cb-9cb6-ebbce0bb78ed
1579219200
{'Object': '108', 'Latitude': 50.15466792673487, 'Longitude': -5.066927538249519}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What would the output look like?

Comment: ```108
df44d8ef-1ace-40cb-9cb6-ebbce0bb78ed
1579219200
{'Object': '108', 'Latitude': 50.15466792673487, 'Longitude': -5.066927538249519}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the codes, `json_doc` looks like a dictionary. We could change the keys using

`dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)`

Do some processing before printing the results:

```
json_doc = {'Object': '108', 'Easting': 50.15466792673487, 'Northing': -5.066927538249519}
json_doc['Latitude'] = json_doc.pop('Easting')
json_doc['Longitude'] = json_doc.pop('Northing')
print(json_doc)
```

Output

```
{'Object': '108', 'Latitude': 50.15466792673487, 'Longitude': -5.066927538249519}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the copy and the deletion of the old keys

```
json_doc['Latitude'] = json_doc['Easting']
del json_doc['Easting'] 
json_doc['Longitude'] = json_doc['Northing']
del json_doc['Northing']
```

Comment: I tried this and got the result ```keys ['Object', 'Easting', 'Northing']
'Easting'```

Comment: @fullaquestions put my code after the `for idx,el in enumerate(row)` loop and when printing `print(json_doc)` you should see it